# Firebase realtime database get parent node value .val()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have the below code that looks for a specific update in my `/users` object tree. 
This works fine, but seems a bit redundant, since I already have a reference to a child of the user node that I want.

```
exports.onUserKeyHelloCreate = functions
.region('europe-west1')
.database
.ref('users/{userId}/hello')
.onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
  const userId = context.params.userId  
  let userData = null
  await database.ref(`users/${userId}`).once('value', (userSnapshot)=>{
    userData = userSnapshot.val()
  })
  console.log('userData', userData)
```

Is there a more elegant way to access the entire user node that does not require an extra roundtrip to `.once('value')`?

Kind regards /K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the entire contents of your database at "users/${userId}", what you're doing now is really the only way to do it.

Though you shouldn't really combine use of the callback along with the promise returned by `once()`.  It's sufficient to just use the promise.

```
const snapshot = await database.ref(`users/${userId}`).once('value');
const userData = snapshot.val();
console.log('userData', userData)
```